# Impossible to write on NTFS disk

Tags: ntfs

I use ubuntu 18.04.4.LTS and I have a second hard disk. This disk is a NTFS partition.
I can't write on this disk (only reading works). I don't have the permission. 
There is no dual boot on my computer. I just replace windows 10 by ubuntu.

Here is my /etc/fstab

```
#Entry for /dev/sdb1 : 
UUID=D4D0FC4ED0FC3876   /media/mickael/D4D0FC4ED0FC3876 ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=fr_FR.UTF-8    0   0
```

I have ntfs-3g. I try ntfs-config but this one doesn't work.
Do you know how to enable the writing on this disk?

Here is the return of the command mount | grep sdb : /dev/sdb1 on /media/mickael/D4D0FC4ED0FC3876 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096) – Mick 1 hour ago

I use this command sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point

Do you know how to keep this configuration after a reboot?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked in the logs to see if there is a reason?   If you type `mount` to list mounts, or `mount |grep sdb` (restrict to sdb only) is it mounted RW?  If not I'd check logs, or `umount` it, re-mount via terminal to view the messages on screen (faster than checking logs which GUI operations require). It could be the file system is damaged & needs `fsck` (file system check) and the RO mounting is to prevent further damage. Is it RO or RW?

Comment: Look at the logs: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /dev/sdb`. Read the `man mount`, and the man pages shown by `dpkg -L ntfs-3g | grep man`.

Comment: here is the return of the command mount | grep sdb : /dev/sdb1 on /media/mickael/D4D0FC4ED0FC3876 type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)

Comment: I use this command sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point